# Bind object property to input and pass value to function on button click in angular

Tags: angular

I want to add text field value to a row in angular 8 when click a button in Angular 8.

page.component.html

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="betOption3type" [formControl]="betOption3" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" style="text-align:right;">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-round waves-effect waves-light m-1" id="addnewrecord" (click)="addRow(betOption3.value)">Add Bet</button>

<tr *ngFor="let row of selectedOptions$ | async">
    <td>{{ row.code.value }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.desc.value }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.amount.value }}</td>
</tr>
```

page.component.ts

```
export class NewBettingComponent implements OnInit {
  betOption = new FormControl();
  betOption2 = new FormControl();
  betOption3 = new FormControl();
  betOption3type = "";
  options$ = new BehaviorSubject([{ id: 1, value: 'Mark Verndom' }, { id: 2, value: 'Jacob Brown' }, { id: 3, value: 'Steve Rogurs' }]);
  options2$ = new BehaviorSubject([{ id: 1, value: 'CSN1' }, { id: 2, value: 'CIA5' }, { id: 3, value: 'CSI7' }]);

  selectedOptions$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){
  }

  addRow() {
    if (!this.betOption.value) {
        return;
    }
    if (!this.betOption2.value) {
      return;
    }
    if (!this.betOption3.value) {
      return;
    }
    const yourSelectedObject = this.options$.value.find(el => el.id === Number(this.betOption.value));
    const yourSelectedObject2 = this.options2$.value.find(el2 => el2.id === Number(this.betOption2.value));
    this.selectedOptions$.next([...this.selectedOptions$.value, {desc: yourSelectedObject, code: yourSelectedObject2, amount: this.betOption3type}]);

}
```

When I try with above code I am getting only two select option values to dynamic `<tr>`. But text field value is not added to dynamic row. How can I solve this.

Comment: `ngModel` and `formControl` aren't meant to be used together. Use either one or the other.

Comment: @nash11 I am fresher to Angular. i try to do this for several days. Can u correct that i was wrong in above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve data binding without the need for `FormControl` using `[(ngModel)]`. You can also bind to a specific object property within the binding.

Any variable you declare in your component can be bound to the input and will automatically be updated when you input into the input box. e.g.

*component.html*

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="betOption.value"  >

<button type="button" (click)="addRow()">Add Bet</button>
```

*component.ts*

```
export class AppComponent  {
  betOption = {value:''}

  addRow() {
    console.log('adding a row with betOption:',this.betOption)
  }
}
```

You can see the code working in the following stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tph54j

*example output*

[image: example output]

Comment: I tried with your code. But when I try to add value to `<tr>` It not workes. I used `<td>{{ row.amount.value }}</td>` this for it. How can I solve this?

Comment: That is due to other issues in the code, but I've updated the stackblitz to keep betOption as an object and bind in the template. Will update the example above and is working

Comment: In that case you should mark this question as resolved as the issue first stated has been, attempt to work the new logic into your component and open a new question if there is a specific error you receive having tried.